# NSArray NSString memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I have a simple method to read a string and parse it to an array,

```
-(NSArray *) readFileToArray: (NSString *)file{
    NSString *values = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: file];
    NSArray *tokens = [values componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    return tokens;
}
```

however instruments did report me I got a leak on NSString at line

```
NSArray *tokens = [values componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

I have no idea why this happens,
1). I think both values and tokens are autoreleased? Am I right?
2). I tried to release values and tokens(just a try), it crashes.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Michael

Comment: If you tag `objective` and `c` you'll only get answers from Objective and C programmers.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is using correct memory management (the return value is autoreleased).  Look at the code that is calling `readFileToArray:` to see how it's handling the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

The line that is leaked is `NSString *values = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: file];`

You need to add autorelease in this line to fix the leak.